# send emails to valid emails in phpMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm using phpMailer to send emails.
Email recipients are passed as an array, and are added by looping through this array. Example:

```
public static function mailTo($recipients)
{
    $f3 = \Base::instance();
    $user = AclHelper::getCurrentUser();
    $template= new \Template;
    $mailBody= $template->render('leave/emailTemp.html');

    // When true, PHPMailer returns exceptions
    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    try {
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->isHTML(true);

        $mail->addAddress($user['email']);
        $mail->addAddress("abhshrestha@growbydata.com");
        $mail->addAddress("rmali@growbydata.com");

        foreach($recipients as $recipient){
            $mail->addAddress($recipient);
        }

        $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
        $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
        $mail->Username = "growbydata.np@gmail.com";
        $mail->Password = "abcd";

        $mail->setFrom($user['email']);

        $userFullName = trim(ucfirst($user['firstname'])) . " " . trim(ucfirst($user['lastname']));
        $mail->FromName = $userFullName;
        $mail->Body =  $f3->get('message');
        $mail->Body .="<br>". $mailBody;
        $mail->Subject = 'Updates on leave date applied';

        $mailStatus = (boolean)$mail->send();

        if ($mailStatus === true) {
            return $mail;
        }
    } catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        $response = array(
            'status'=>'error',
            'message'=>'Got some error while sending emails',
            'exceptions'=>$e->getMessage()
        );
        return $response;

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $response = array(
            'status'=>'error',
            'message'=>'Got some error while sending emails',
            'exceptions'=>$e->getMessage()
        );

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Emails are being sent to and received by recipients whose addresses are set statically. eg.

```
$mail->addAddress("abhshrestha@growbydata.com");
    $mail->addAddress("rmali@growbydata.com");
```

The problem is that there might exist some "invalid" emails among these recipients. For eg. `"rakesh@idontcare.com"`.

It seems that whenever phpMailer encounters these type of addresses, it doesn't send emails to any other "valid" addresses as well.

How can I make PhpMailer work such that "valid" emails receive emails like in Gmail.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `rakesh@idontcare.com` is a valid email address. It might not exist, but it's valid. If an address is "non existing", PHPMailer won't stop sending to the other addresses. PHPMailer just sends the email to the SMTP server, which is the server that actually does the sending. So as far as PHPMailer is concerned, it went well as long as the SMTP server just received the request.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson But existing addresses are also not receiving emails when they are looped from an array. Only those addresses set statically are receiving emails.

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. I read it as it works in the loop until it reaches an "invalid address", as you call it. If it _never_ works for address you add in the loop,  then do a `print_r($recipients);` and add the output to your question.

Comment: I did.. hello@gmail.com is an existing email address. 
Also checking list of other recipients, hello@gmail.com is listed and shown online, meaning the address is active. But no email is received.

Comment: How do you know it's not received? Is it your account? If yes, checked the spam folder? There can be may reasons why an email doesn't reach the recipient. This question is still pretty unclear. You stated in your question _"It seems that whenever phpMailer encounters these type of addresses, it doesn't send emails to any other "valid" addresses as well."_ - How did you confirm this and how did you confirm that it's PHPMailer that doesn't send those and not that they go to the spam folder or similar? Or that it's just "other" emails after an "invalid" address that doesn't work?

Comment: yes.. I have statically set my `existing` address to receive email, and also to check who else are the other recipients. And also in `$recipients` array, I have set my other `existing` email among other `non-existing` addresses.
I am receiving email at my address that is set statically but not in other account which is listed in `$recipients` array

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I tried sending emails with both `existing` and `non-existing` addresses, but this time I only added few 7-8 addresses as recipients. And this time, `existing` addresses are receiving emails. While in other case, there are more than 130 recipients. Could this be the problem?

Comment: _"While in other case, there are more than 130 recipients"_ - There you go. Most SMTP servers will block you if you're trying to send to that many at one point. (I think Gmail have a limit of 100 recipients per email when using their SMTP.) If you need to send that many, you need to use some SMTP server that allows for this, like Amazon SES or similar.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson One last thing. So when I'm sending emails to those 130+ recipients from GMAIL directly, `existing` addresses are receiving it. But doing the same thing using phpMailer and Gmail as SMTP server will limit recipients and hence causing this issue. Am I right?

Comment: Most likely, yes. Sending through their interface, I think the limit is about 500, but through their SMTP, it's 100.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check if the PHPMAILER is getting some error.

You should use this two lines in order to be able to see the result of PHPMailer about errors.

```
mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; //Alternative to above constant
```

If you get some problem to read the information you can pass the output were and I try to help to analyse.